# external Horizontal scroll bar with datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to use external horizontal scroll bar with data grid view instead of its own.

Hide the data grid's scroll and use the external scroll bar to scroll the grid
How can i achieve this.

Comment: You can do it by putting it in an auto-scroll panel and making the `DataGridView` auto-size. But why not using the control's scrollbars?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want to add footer, i placed the grid in panel and i want to add footer panel at bottom of main panel.